# How to log all SQL queries for a single connection or user or client host?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, log

Is there a way to log all SQL queries in Postgres 9.3.9 for a single connection or user or client host?

In other words, I want `log_statement = all` but only for a certain username or client hostname or client ip or connection id.

One option is to log SQL activity for all clients and search the logs. I'm hoping there's a better way.

Comment: To allow filtering logs you need to setup `log_line_prefix`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know how to do it for a client host, but for a single database user, you can use this (as a superuser):

```
ALTER ROLE someone SET log_statement TO 'all';
```

Which will then turn on log_statement every time that that `someone` connects in the future.

For a single connection which is cooperating with you, you could create this function (as a superuser):

```
create or replace function set_log_statement() returns void as $$
 set log_statement='all' 
$$ language sql security definer ;
```

And then have the desired single connection invoke this function to turn on logging for itself.