# enable query log for single database

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, logins

I am having many database schema in mysql 5.6 server, now the problem over here is that I want to catch the queries for one schema only.

I can not enable query log for entire server as one of my schema is highly loaded and it will impact the server.

Is their any way, any tool through which I could only log the queries by single schema.

I found benchmarking graph which shows the impact on transactions/second when query log is enabled.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you use slow query log instead? And then parse that log with pt-query-digest? If not you can try tcpdump output parsed by pt-query-digest

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question and a +1. I was interested by this because I can see several use cases for this fuctionality.

Unfortunately, for your case where you **cannot** switch on general logging, there is only one, rather inadequate, workaround.

That is to use the [SQL_LOG_OFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_log_off) variable to disable logging for a given connection. An ideal solution would have been to have an "SQL_LOG_ON" variable as one can do in Oracle (equivalent) - maybe you could try and switch logging off for all but the connection(s) of interest?

Furthermore, and regretably, this requires the `SUPER` privilege. Again, this may not (even probably not) be possible in your case.

Depending on the severity of your problem, working hours and server load at given times, you may be able to find a use for Percona's [pt-query-digest](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-query-digest.html) which can help with log analysis. Small comfort, but as usual PostgreSQL is streets ahead of MySQL ([1](https://serverfault.com/questions/376699/postgresql-log-queries-single-database), [2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/116163/34007)).

If you'd care to file a feature request, I'd be happy to follow up with a "me-too" if you post the link back here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are so close to keeling over that you can't turn on the General log to FILE, you have worse problems; they need fixing.

I suspect, without any real knowledge, that the slowlog would have similar impact, especially with `long_query_time = 0`.

5.7 has a "query rewrite" feature.  Some trick might be used there.  (But, again, there is some overhead, which should be benchmarked.)

How long to you want to catch the queries?  Are you just looking for the source of one naughty action?  Or are you trying to gather queries to build a realistic benchmark for that table?  Or something else?

Do you have replication turned on?  Are you interested in reads?  Or writes?  Or both?

How many threads are *active* concurrently?  The benchmark you showed indicated that for 1, the log has low overhead.  It is the table lock on MyISAM or CSV that is killing the processing for high concurrency.

Your second graph points out that the *clients* should really be restricted to about 5-8 concurrent connections -- else throughput actually declines!  What were `max_connections` and `Max_used_connections` for that graph?

Comment: Hi, I want to capture the queries for about 2 days and these graphs are not related to my benchmarking...I pasted them for knowledge sake only.The app for which I want the queries is a low resource consumer. Tcpdump will not provide the timing stats.